# private static ClassName ClassInstanceVariableName=null;.....what is this?

Tags: java, methods, static, static-methods

Well there is a static implementation here, I don't understand.I have previously used static but not extensively, can anyone help me to understand the code. Here is the code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class Connection_Class {
String driver_ClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String URL_connection="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vendor";
String user="root";
String password="lifesuckzz";
   //can anybody explain what the following line means, especially the static part.......
    private static Connection_Class connectionclass=null;

private Connection_Class(){
    try{
        Class.forName(driver_ClassName);

    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
    Connection con=null;
    con=DriverManager.getConnection(URL_connection,user,password);
    return con;
}

public static Connection_Class getInstance(){
    if(connectionclass==null){
                 //I know its returning an instance here
        connectionclass=new Connection_Class();
    }
    return connectionclass;
}


}
```

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html - if you don't understand what `static` means, I *strongly* suggest you learn more about core Java language features before doing any database work.

Comment: The only reason a static instance is used to hold the class instance is so the static method `getInstance` can access it.... I'm sure all the answers below will tell you why this singleton is not going to work as a singleton....

Comment: @Thihara: got it....that was exactly where I had this conceptual doubt...

Comment: @JonSkeet: thnk u for the reference...i was actually looking for an answer what thihara(above) and old Pro(below) have given....

Comment: @Why-K-Rum: You say "I know the reason static is used" - but there's nothing within Old Pro's answer which goes beyond that, really. Which bit of that did you *not* know before?

Comment: Additionally, the first several sentences of your question are completely irrelevant (and I'll remove them).

Comment: @JonSkeet: im sorry if my comment offended u in any way...when I stated i know the reason why static is used..i meant I knew how static is used in various cases...but I am new to this kind of case...thank you...

Comment: @Why-K-Rum: It's not a matter of being offended. It's a matter of trying to run before you can walk - I think it's important to try to understand the core of the language before you start doing things like database work.

Comment: @JonSkeet : i have no time to walk right now...i wish I had... :) but I will keep that advice in mind .. (:

Comment: You'll be wasting time then - your own and other people's. Honestly, you'll find you get to the end goal much quicker if you learn things in a sensible order. Trying to take shortcuts will only land you in trouble. I've seen it loads of times.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30747/discussion-between-why-k-rum-and-jon-skeet)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`static` means that the variable is a member of the class itself (only one copy) rather than a member of objects of the class (one per object).  You can access a `static` variable without having an object.  In this case you can call `Connection_Class.getInstance()` to get the single `Connection_Class` object shared by the whole program.

Answer (score 2):

It's a **design pattern** called **Singleton Design Pattern**.

> This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

*Answer to your question* :

Singletons maintain a static reference to the sole singleton instance and return a reference to that instance from a static getInstance() method.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a `Singleton` design pattern. By marking the constructor private you ensure that you *control instantiation to have ***one and only one*** instance per JVM*.

```
public final class Singleton {

    private static Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

    private Singleton () {
        if (INSTANCE != null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Already instantiated.");
    }

    // getInstance() method here (refer below)
}
```

The keyword `static` ***ensures that the Singleton becomes accessible as a member of the class*** (like `Singleton.getInstance()`) without requiring a constructor call which isn't possible now since it has been marked `private`.

Also, your Singleton implementation is not thread-safe. *Synchronize* your `getInstance()` method.

```
public static synchronized Connection_Class getInstance(){
    if(connectionclass == null){
        connectionclass = new Connection_Class();
    }
    return connectionclass;
}
```

This avoids any race condition between multiple threads requesting this connection object.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of the *singleton* pattern. It creates *one* reference of the connection class within your app (strictly speaking, within your classloader).

[Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is a fairly common pattern in many OO langauges, but is often seen as an anti-pattern since it makes testing difficult.